# Saving a Pdf to internal storage

Tags: android, pdf

I am working in an app to download some pdf files from web to the phone. I know how to download file from the web. I use FirebaseStorage but I don't know how to save this file to internal storage and load it when the user want to use it.

So how can I save pfd file to internal storage and load it? This is my code to download the file from FirebaseStorage

```
StorageRef.child(adapterView.getItemAtPosition(i)+".pdf");
            try {
                getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_TOUCHABLE,
                        WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_TOUCHABLE);
                progressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                final File localFile = File.createTempFile("filename","pdf");
                StorageRef.getFile(localFile).addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<FileDownloadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<FileDownloadTask.TaskSnapshot> task) {

                        Toast.makeText(ShowActivity.this, "Download Successful", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        getWindow().clearFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_TOUCHABLE);
                        progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    }
                });
            }catch (Exception e){
                System.out.println(e);         
   }
```

Comment: Your catch block is empty. So if there is a catch you know nothing. Put the usual code in it and a Toast() to inform the user if there is one. Do you have an Exception now? Please edit your post with the added code.

Answer (score -1):

You will find the solution here :

https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/files.html

Comment: is the pdf file save like a string?

Comment: No he is saved like a normal pdf file.

Comment: how ? in the link you sent to me for string